# Converting STUFF + FOR XML from SQL to Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
[Project Numbers]= STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + Fin2.[ID]
        FROM table Fin2
        WHERE In.Investment_Key = Fin2.PROJECT_KEY
        FOR XML PATH('')
         ), 1, 1, '')
```

I can't quite figure out how to convert this to snowflake as I am still trying to learn it, is there a STUFF equivalent?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `LISTAGG`:

```
SELECT In.Investment_Key, LISTAGG(Fin2.[ID], ',') AS "Project Numbers"
FROM In
LEFT JOIN table Fin2
  ON  In.Investment_Key = Fin2.PROJECT_KEY 
GROUP BY In.Investment_Key;
```

`STUFF + FOR XML` is an old workaround used for version of SQL Server that does not support [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) natively. The Snwoflake equivalent is [LISTAGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg.html) function that could work either as aggregate or windowed function.

---

Addendum:

The SQL Standard [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) equivalent is called `OVERLAY` with signature as follow:

```
OVERLAY <left paren> <character value expression>
        PLACING <character value expression>
        FROM <start position>
        [ FOR <string length> ] <right paren>
```