# What will be Equivalent Mapping for FORMAT,STUFF & FOR XML PATH in Snowflake?

Tags: function, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking for the Function Mapping(AzureSQL to Snowflake) for the Below Functions:
'FORMAT', 'STUFF' & 'FOR XML PATH'.
Please provide Equivalent for below examples in Snowflake.

For "FORMAT":

Example1:

```
SELECT TOP(5) CurrencyRateID, EndOfDayRate
,FORMAT(EndOfDayRate, 'N', 'en-us') AS 'Number Format'
,FORMAT(EndOfDayRate, 'G', 'en-us') AS 'General Format'
,FORMAT(EndOfDayRate, 'C', 'en-us') AS 'Currency Format'
FROM Sales.CurrencyRate
ORDER BY CurrencyRateID;
```

Example2:

```
Select FORMAT(CAST('2018-01-01 14:00' AS datetime2), N'HH:mm')
```

For STUFF, FOR XML PATH

Example1:

```
select stuff((select CONCAT(',', cast(CONCAT(C_Key,',',A_Key,',',A_Number) as varchar(max)))
from db.Table a where A_Number= '2134'
and IsLatest = 1 FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'');
```

Comment: Those functions are typically used as a convoluted workaround for a missing `listagg()`, `group_concat()` or `string_agg()` functions. Search for something like that in Snowflake

Comment: You definitely should define what is your data and what is the expected output. Not just random code in some other database (maybe SQL Server?) that you haven't even mentioned. And of course tell what you've attempted so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting STUFF + FOR XML from SQL to Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68118218/converting-stuff-for-xml-from-sql-to-snowflake)